# Reform is updating the wrong table on populating with collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, reform

I am a new user of the gem Reform. 
My goal is to update a table named `shared_files` and one of its associated tables `shared_files_user_accounts`. I guess the update works fine for both except Reform is somewhat trying to update another of its associated table named `user_accounts`, wich it must not. 
My properties are the following :

```
class SharedFileUploadForm < Reform::Form 
model :shared_file
property :filename
property :file, virtual: true
collection :user_accounts,
          populate_if_empty: lambda {|fragment, _|
            user_account= UserAccount.filter(email_address: fragment["email_address"])
          } do
  property :email_address, validates: { presence: true }  
end
validate :only_existing_user_accounts

def only_existing_user_accounts
  return if user_accounts.all?(&:persisted?)
  errors.add(:user_accounts, "must already exist")
 end
end
```

Then in the `shared_files` model, I update data in `shared_files_user_accounts`:

```
  def user_accounts=(collection)
    shared_file_user_accounts_dataset.delete

    add_shared_file_user_account(SharedFileUserAccount.new(shared_file_id: shared_file_id, user_account_id: owner_id))

    collection.each do |user_account|
      add_shared_file_user_account(SharedFileUserAccount.new(shared_file_id: shared_file_id, user_account_id: user_account.id))
    end
  end
```

Here is the error message from postgre:

```
[ERROR] unicorn worker[0] --port xxxx:yyyy - PG::UniqueViolation: 
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint    "user_accounts_email_address_key"
DETAIL:  Key (email_address)=(EMAIL@ADDRESS) already exists.: UPDATE "user_accounts" SET ...
```

Thank you very much!